# ionic cordova platform add [platform] - npm not recognized

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to remove the windows platform from my ionic project. Now I get the following error:

[image]

As you can see the error says that npm is not recognized but when I try the 'unrecognized command' myself it works fine.

Any solution/workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extremely old version of npm. Depending on which version of Ionic you have installed, they may be incompatible. Try updating npm:

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```